# Laravel AJAX Patch - send _method:'patch' in the data

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send some data via AJAX to my Laravel app.

I'm using jQuery for the AJAX bit.

The `HTTP method` I am trying to do it with is `PATCH`.

I want to include the method name (patch) in the `data` and keep the `type` as `POST`, as this will ensure greater browser-compatibility.

I set everything up using `PATCH` as the `type`, and all was working fine.

Then I changed the `type` to `POST` and put the 'spoofed' method name in the `data`. Then things stopped working.

Here is my current AJAX code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        url: ajaxURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringiy({_method: "PATCH", more_data:[the_data]}),
        dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
    });
```

Now, the above does work in the sense that it successfully runs. But Laravel does not recognise the spoofed method (and throws a MethodNotAllowed exception)... It does recognise the spoofed `method` and all works, when I don't use `JSON.stringify` on the `data`, but I need to do it this way for everything to work.

I feel I am very close, and I just need to put some code, maybe a new middleware class and route these requests through it, so that I can successfully spoof the `PATCH HTTP` method?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to Laravel check request method (`vendor/Symfony/http-foundation/Request.php`)

```
public function getMethod()
{
    if (null === $this->method) {
        $this->method = strtoupper($this->server->get('REQUEST_METHOD', 'GET'));

        if ('POST' === $this->method) {
            if ($method = $this->headers->get('X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE')) {
                $this->method = strtoupper($method);
            } elseif (self::$httpMethodParameterOverride) {
                $this->method = strtoupper($this->request->get('_method', $this->query->get('_method', 'POST')));
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->method;
}
```

As you can see you need send `X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE` header for correct route handle. In your case you can just add

```
headers: { 'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH' },
```